# jQuery trigger click gives "too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, event-bubbling

I'm tryin' to make the article's link clickable on the whole article space.

First, I did the hover thing, changing color on mouseover and so on... then on click it should trigger the link, but this gives a "too much recursion".

I think it's a `event bubbling` problem. I tried to work with `event.cancelBubble = true;` or `stopPropagation()` with no luck. Worse luck!

anyone?

```
    $("div.boxContent").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".btn").length) {

            var $fade = $(this).find("div.btn a > span.hover");
            var $title = $(this).find("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5");
            var $span = $(this).find("span").not("span.hover");
            var $text = $(this).find("p");

            var titleColor = $title.css('color');
            var spanColor = $span.css('color');

            $(this).css({'cursor':'pointer'}).bind({
                mouseenter:function() {
                    $text.stop().animate({color:linkHover},textAnim);
                    $title.stop().animate({color:linkHover},textAnim);
                    $span.stop().animate({color:linkHover},textAnim);
                    $fade.stop(true,true).fadeIn(textAnim);
                }, mouseleave:function() {
                    $text.stop().animate({color:linkColor},textAnim);
                    $title.stop().animate({color:titleColor},textAnim);
                    $span.stop().animate({color:spanColor},textAnim);
                    $fade.stop(true,true).fadeOut(textAnim);
                }, focusin:function() {
                    $text.stop().animate({color:linkHover},textAnim);
                    $title.stop().animate({color:linkHover},textAnim);
                    $span.stop().animate({color:linkHover},textAnim);
                    $fade.stop(true,true).fadeIn(textAnim);
                }, focusout:function() {
                    $text.stop().animate({color:linkColor},textAnim);
                    $title.stop().animate({color:titleColor},textAnim);
                    $span.stop().animate({color:spanColor},textAnim);
                    $fade.stop(true,true).fadeOut(textAnim);
                }
            }).click(function() {
                $(this).find("div.btn a").trigger('click');
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problematic bit of your code is this:

```
$("div.boxContent") /* miss the each function */
.click(function() {
    $(this).find("div.btn a").trigger('click');
});
```

This says "every time any click event is received on this element, trigger a click on the descendant element".  However, event bubbling means that the event triggered in this function is then handled again by this event handler, *ad infinitum*.  The best way to stop this is, I think, to see if the event originated on the `div.btn a` element.  You could use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) and [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target) for this:

```
$("div.boxContent") /* miss the each function */
.click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('div.btn a')) {
        $(this).find("div.btn a").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

This says "if the click originated on any element apart from a `div.btn a`, trigger a click event on `div.btn a`.  This means that events caused by the `trigger` call will not be handled by this function.  This is superior to checking `event.target == this` (as [Andy's answer has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967923/jquery-trigger-click-gives-too-much-recursion/5967956#5967956)) because it can cope with other elements existing within the `div.boxContent`.

Comment: +1, you're right, that is superior to the check I suggested.  Deleted in favour.  I do think a better approach is cancelling the bubble from the `div.btn a` element, however, as I'm not a fan of using the inefficient `is()` function.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand! This do the trick. Thank you lonesomeday.

Answer (score -1):

A cleaner way to solve this is to take the the element you are triggering the click on to and put it outside of the triggered element:

So if you have this:

```
<div class="boxContent">

    <div class="btn">
        <a href="#">link</a> <!-- move this line... -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ... to here. -->

<script>
$("div.boxContent") /* miss the each function */
    .click(function() {
    $(this).find("div.btn a").trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

By moving the "div.btn a" tag outside of the "boxContent" div. You avoid the recursion loop all together.